# Install database script in C #

Tags: c#, sql-server

We created a C # program with entity framework
Now I'm having trouble making the setup, because if this program is installed on another system it will be difficult to miss the database.
This program automatically installs sql server engine. Now my problem is the installation of the database.
I would like a code to check when installing whether or not there is a database on the engine, if not, install a script file that our database is installed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [Database Initialization Stategy](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) and I'd recommend this one to meet your requirements:

> **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**: This is **default** initializer. As the name suggests, it will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception.

The page I linked also includes an example of how to implement the strategy:

```
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
{

    public SchoolDBContext(): base("SchoolDBConnectionString") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SchoolDBContext>());

        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SchoolDBContext>());
        //Database.SetInitializer<SchoolDBContext>(new SchoolDBInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first migrations, you could generate the requiered sql-scripts. I believe you already have the scripts to run, so that won't be a problem.

If Initializers won't do the trick, You could take a look at custom actions.
You can then run a program with the permissions of the system/user running the setup to check of if the database (or server) exists. And if not create it.

Assuming you are creating a msi setup take a look here. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I used sp_attach_db for attach database.
But he tells me that Attach the database successfully
But something is not attached to SQL Server
When I run two runs, the program says that The database is available
or 
(Database 'TellDB' already exists. Choose a different database name.
Changed database context to 'master'.)

```
try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;";
            con.Open();

            string str = "USE master;" +
           "EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'TellDB' , " +
             " @filename1 = N'" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Data\\TellDB.mdf'," +
             "@filename2 = N'" + System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Data\\TellDB_log.ldf'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Attach the database successfully");

        }

        catch (Exception x)
        {
            if (x.Message.IndexOf("already exists") >= 0)
                MessageBox.Show("The database is available");

            else
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
```